# multik vectorized subtraction and multiplication

Tags: android, matrix

I am looking to perform the following on android using multik and I have been unsuccessful:
Given

```
    A = [3x3]
    v = [nx3]
    C = [1x3]

    result = A*(v-C)
```

Is there a way to perform the subtraction of [nx3] - [1x3] ?
Similarly, can the multiplication of [3x3] * [3xn] be done?

On the Quick Start guide , the multiplication example (f*d) seems to show element-wise multiplication not vector multiplication.

Any recommendations to use different libraries is welcome.

Thanks